# ReactJs print value of input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to print instantly my input value in the render function.

In the documentation of the [concept of state and lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) in a React component, I see the use of a `constructor` with a `super(props)` as well as `this.state`.

I get the error below when trying same;

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Below is my code;

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: ''
    };
  };

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      text: event.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.state.text}.</h2>
        <input type="text" onKeyUp={this.handleChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this) in constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you call a function like that, it is called by the window, not by your react object.

To make the function be bound to your react object (and have the ability to use the setState method, you need to use this:

`onKeyUp={this.handleChange.bind(this)}`

`this` will bind it to your react object :)

Comment: What @Burak said in the comment on your question about binding it in the constructor is also a good suggestion, especially if you will use the function anywhere else on your page.  If you have bound it in the constructor, then you can simply call  `this.handleChange` anywhere else on your page.

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind `this` to your event handler like this:

```
<input type="text" onKeyUp={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
```

Working Example: https://codepen.io/shanedaugherty/pen/ALwAzL

Comment: Working example isn't opening.

Answer (score 1):

`this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);`
You can bind it like this in constructor and it will work, as you have to bind this to your react function.

Answer (score 0):

You use value as an attribute.

```
value={this.state.text}
```

OR